# No member named 'setRawData' in 'QwtPlotCurve' - Convert Qt 4.7 to Qt 5.8

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I need to **convert Qt legacy code from 4.7 to 5.8**, I have a compilation error in Qt Creator 4.2.1 Clang 7.0(Apple) 64bit.

**Looking in .cpp file**

```
#include "mpiChartCurve.h"
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>


mpiChartCurve::mpiChartCurve(QwtPlot *chart_):
    m_chart(chart_),
    m_curve(new QwtPlotCurve())
{
}

mpiChartCurve::~mpiChartCurve()
{
    // be default qwt will delete the curve when it is destroyed
    // only delete the curve when detach is called
}

void mpiChartCurve::detach()
{
    m_curve->detach();

    // hack for now?  qwt doesn't seem to redraw properly until a curve is attached after a detachment, so attach dummy
    QVector<double> x, y;
    m_curve->setRawData(x.constData(), y.constData(), 0); // JDL convert Qt4 to Qt5  BROKE
    m_curve->attach(m_chart);
    m_curve->detach();

    delete m_curve;
    m_curve = 0;
}


void mpiChartCurve::attach()
{
    if (!m_curve)
        return;

    m_curve->setRawData(m_xData.constData(),m_yData.constData(), count()); // JDL convert Qt4 to Qt5  BROKE
    m_curve->attach(m_chart);
}
```

**2 Errors in .cpp**

../src/usercontrols/mpiChartCurve.cpp:23:14: **error: no member named 'setRawData' in 'QwtPlotCurve'**
    m_curve->setRawData(x.constData(), y.constData(), 0); // JDL convert Qt4 to Qt5  BROKE
    ~~~~~~~  ^

../src/usercontrols/mpiChartCurve.cpp:37:14: **error: no member named 'setRawData' in 'QwtPlotCurve'**
    m_curve->setRawData(m_xData.constData(),m_yData.constData(), count()); // JDL convert Qt4 to Qt5  BROKE
    ~~~~~~~  ^

**2 errors generated**
make: *** [mpiChartCurve.o] Error 1
21:12:40: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project mypersonalindex (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"

The Qt5 Docs mentioned **setRawData**

```
QByteArray &    setRawData(const char *data, uint size)
```

I did notice this comment in doc for QByteArray

(obsolete)  operator const char *() const

My C++ skill is pretty limited, do you see any minor tweaks that could convert this from Qt4 to Qt5. ... so what is the replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setRawData is not a member function of QwtPlotCurve. It is a member function of QByteArray and it only accepts 2 arguments. Change setRawData to setRawSamples, setRawSamples is a member function of QwtPlotCurve and accepts the three arguments you're looking for.

Fixed version

```
#include "mpiChartCurve.h"
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>


mpiChartCurve::mpiChartCurve(QwtPlot *chart_):
    m_chart(chart_),
    m_curve(new QwtPlotCurve())
{
}

mpiChartCurve::~mpiChartCurve()
{
    // be default qwt will delete the curve when it is destroyed
    // only delete the curve when detach is called
}

void mpiChartCurve::detach()
{
    m_curve->detach();

    // hack for now?  qwt doesn't seem to redraw properly until a curve is attached after a detachment, so attach dummy
    QVector<double> x, y;
    m_curve->setRawSamples(x.constData(), y.constData(), 0); // JDL convert Qt4 to Qt5  BROKE
    m_curve->attach(m_chart);
    m_curve->detach();

    delete m_curve;
    m_curve = 0;
}


    void mpiChartCurve::attach()
{
    if (!m_curve)
        return;

    m_curve->setRawSamples(m_xData.constData(),m_yData.constData(), count()); // JDL convert Qt4 to Qt5  BROKE
    m_curve->attach(m_chart);
}
```